# Spring Cloud API Gateway : Resilience4j : Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm trying to implement circuit breaker on my cloud gateway using spring cloud resilience4j, getting "Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker
" error.

Dependencies I'm using

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Spring Cloud Version:

```xml
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
```

Main Class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class CloudGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml configuration

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: CLOUD-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: USER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/users/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: userCircuitBreaker
                fallbackuri: forward:/userServiceFallBack
        - id: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/departments/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: departmentCircuitBreaker
                fallbackuri: forward:/departmentServiceFallBack


resilience4j:
  retry:
    instances:
      myRetry:
        max-attempts: 3
        wait-duration: 5s
```

Based on the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-filter-factory the configuration to me looks fine, if I'm missing anything?

I have went trough the suggestions provided under [Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263386/unable-to-find-gatewayfilterfactory-with-name-circuitbreaker) and related posts, nothing is working for me.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:176) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:328) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:552) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2644) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2044) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        ... 81 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
                at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2645) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
                ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding below dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: tried that it did not work.