# Project doen`t work on intellij but works on eclipe or by command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm creating a gateway, using spring cloud gateway. I created a custom Gateway filter expanding the AbstractGatewayFilterFactory

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthenticationFilter.Config> {

    @Autowired
    private RouteValidator validator;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate template;

    public AuthenticationFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
            if (validator.isSecured.test(exchange.getRequest())) {
                //header contains token or not
                if (!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("missing authorization header");
                }

                String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
                if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    authHeader = authHeader.substring(7);
                }
                try {
//                    //REST call to AUTH service
                    String forObject = template.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/validateToken?token=" + authHeader, String.class);
//                    jwtUtil.validateToken(authHeader);
                    System.out.println(forObject);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("invalid access...!");
                    throw new RuntimeException("un authorized access to application");
                }
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        });
    }

    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

here my properties

```
---
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: produto
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/produto
          filters:
            - AuthenticationFilter
        - id: authentication
          uri: http://localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/**
  application:
    name: api-gateway
server:
  port: 8082
```

when I start the through intellij app i get the following error

```
023-06-30T14:44:32.460-03:00 ERROR 2296433 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.gateway.route.CachingRouteLocator  : Refresh routes error !!!

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name AuthenticationFilter
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:489) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:422) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:328) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:552) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8671) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8671) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4551) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4452) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4388) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4360) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.CachingRouteLocator.onApplicationEvent(CachingRouteLocator.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.CachingRouteLocator.onApplicationEvent(CachingRouteLocator.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:413) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:413) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at com.gateway.ApiGatewayApplication.main(ApiGatewayApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
```

I looks like that for some reason it can find the custom filter that I defined.

if I try to use eclipe, or build the project using mvn install than start the jar it runs normaly without any error

Comment: Please try suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263386/unable-to-find-gatewayfilterfactory-with-name-circuitbreaker